# Aerospike : Asynchronous Replication : Success at Master and Failure at Replica

Tags: distributed-computing, aerospike, nosql

Aerospike supports ACID in clustered environment with replication factor greater than 1, where any write will be written to Master and Replica and then only it will be marked as success to the client.

But, we can change the above mentioned default behaviour by changing the ***write.commit_level*** from ***all*** to ***master***.

In such case, suppose the write/update is successful at Master node and client is notified, but the write fails at Replica node, What would happen?

Will the Aerospike have inconsistent data for same key in the cluster?
Or will it be retried at Replica?
Or will the write on the Master be rolled back?

Note the Replica node is not down, just the write failed due to any reason like ***stop writes pct*** is breached at Replica node, etc.

Answer (score 2):

if you choose `write.commit_level=master`, and if the prole write fails the client will not be notified about the failure. The replica will stay inconsistent with the master. The master write will not be rolled back. The replica will get fixed on the next write with successful replication. i.e it will get overwritten with latest record.

BTW, an important thing to note is that `stop-writes` is honored at the master and not at the replica. It will be a bad idea to fail the replica write because of this. As long as you have some head room in terms of memory (no malloc failures) and disk, there are hardly any chances of replica write failure when the node itself did not go down.

Comment: Thanks Sunil for your reply. The first part about inconsistency in Master and replica in such scenario is clear.

About the second part, stop-writes being honoured only at Primary, did you encounter this in your production or is present in the Aerospike documentation itself. I could not find much about this.